# How to display minimal variable product price on product page WooCommerce

Tags: woocommerce

I need to display the price of a product in the form with woocommerce-variation single_variation container when loading the product page without selecting options

Page loaded - default variations unset:

[image: Page loaded - default variations unset]

Options selected:

[image: Options selected]

I tried to use some hooks from similar questions but none of them worked